# How to handle redirect in reactJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I'm using React as frontend application and Rails API server, if a user tries to hit go to an authenticated resource I send a 302 redirect response from RAILS API, how to handle it and redirect the React Application to /login page.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try looking into react-router

Comment: @TimGerhard I'm using react-router, but I'm asking how to handle that API response?
the response 302 from rails API is not redirecting in react application?

Comment: you can use react routers Redirect feature to redirect if you ajax / axios / fetch call fails. you can catch failed calls with .catch() (instead of .then()) and then programmatically redirect. BTW why are you returning a 302 for unauthenticated instead of a 401?

Comment: Yeah, I can use 401 too, Cool 
Thanks